# Is it possible to use Sharepoint API in an external app/website?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have used the SharePoint REST API to upload the files to SharePoint but, I have been wondering if it is possible to use the Sharepoint API inside my website to make it seamless to handle file uploads.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: Still not completely clear about the usage.